# How do we install npm pdf-parse library in jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, cypress, docker-container

While running the Cypress tests on jenkins, I am getting the below error. Our jenkins is integrated with Docker container and devs asked me to install the `pdf-parse` library in docker container which will solve the issue. How do I install `pdf-parse` in docker container, which file does that ? Could some one please advise ?

Note: I am unable to see a docker file in my project root directory

```
11:38:29  Or you might have renamed the extension of your `pluginsFile`. If that's the case, restart the test runner.
11:38:29  
11:38:29  Please fix this, or set `pluginsFile` to `false` if a plugins file is not necessary for your project.
11:38:29  
11:38:29   Error: Cannot find module 'pdf-parse'
```

---

docker file:

```
FROM cypress/browsers:node12.14.1-chrome85-ff81

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install --save-dev cypress
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify

# there is a built-in user "node" that comes from the very base Docker Node image
# we are going to recreate this user and give it _same id_ as external user
# that is going to run this container.
ARG USER_ID=501
ARG GROUP_ID=999

# if you want to see all existing groups uncomment the next command
# RUN cat /etc/group

RUN groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} appuser
# do not log creating new user, otherwise there could be a lot of messages
RUN useradd -r --no-log-init -u ${USER_ID} -g appuser appuser
RUN install -d -m 0755 -o appuser -g appuser /home/appuser

# move test runner binary folder to the non-root's user home directory
RUN mv /root/.cache /home/appuser/.cache

USER appuser
```

jenkins file:

```
 pipeline {
      agent {
        docker {
          image 'abcdtest'
          args '--link postgres:postgres  -v /.composer:/.composer'
        }
      }
      options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
      }
      stages {
        stage("print env variables") {
          steps {
            script {
              echo sh(script: 'env|sort', returnStdout: true)
            }
          }
        }
        stage("composer install") {
          steps {
            script {
                
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'bitbucket-api', passwordVariable: 'bitbucketPassword', usernameVariable: 'bitbucketUsername')]) {
                    def authProperties = readJSON file: 'auth.json.dist'
                    authProperties['http-basic']['bitbucket.sometest.com']['username'] = bitbucketUsername
                    authProperties['http-basic']['bitbucket.sometest.com']['password'] = bitbucketPassword
                    writeJSON file: 'auth.json', json: authProperties
                }
            }
            sh 'php composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-progress'
          }
        }
        stage('unit tests') {
          steps {
            lock('ABCD Unit Tests') {
              script {
                try {
                  sh 'mv codeception.yml.dist codeception.yml'
                  sh 'mv tests/unit.suite.yml.jenkins tests/unit.suite.yml'
                  sh 'php vendor/bin/codecept run tests/unit --html'
                }
                catch (err) {
                  echo "unit tests step failed"
                  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                }
                finally {
                  publishHTML (target: [
                    allowMissing: false,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'tests/_output/',
                    reportFiles: 'report.html',
                    reportName: "Unit Tests Report"
                  ])
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      post {
        success {
          slackSend color: 'good', channel: '#jenkins-abcdtest-ci', message: "*SUCCESSED* - CI passed successfully for *${env.BRANCH_NAME}* (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}>)"
        }
        failure {
          slackSend color: 'danger', channel: '#jenkins-abcdtest-ci', message: "*FAILED* - CI failed for *${env.BRANCH_NAME}* (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}> - <${env.BUILD_URL}console|click here to see the console output>)"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use `cypress/base:10` as the image to new a container in jenkins. If you don't have dockerfile, you may have to write your own dockerfile extends from `cypress/base:10`.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM cypress/base:10
RUN npm install pdf-parse
```

Then, `docker build -t mycypress .`, `docker push mycypress` to push the image to dockerhub(You may need an account) to let your jenkins use your new image to setup container.

NOTE: you will have to find how your project choose image to start your container, with this, you can find suitable way to install `pdf-parse`. One possible maybe next:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'cypress/base:10' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you may change `docker { image 'cypress/base:10' }` to `docker { image 'mycypress' }`.

Comment: Sorry I have lately found the ```jenkins file``` and a ```docker file```,  so one question why can't docker or jenkins can't install the all of the required libraries mentioned in package.json ?

Comment: In my case should I need to add `RUN npm install pdf-parse` in the above my docker file ? will solve the issue ?

Comment: `docker image` is a prebuilt binary image, the `pdf-parse` is a dependency, typically, you should do it in your own dockerfiles in advance. Not install it again and again when jenkins run your project, it waste time. YES, it should work to put install in your dockerfile, but depends how you jenkins use the image, you may push to dockerhub, or you may have a local docker registery.

Comment: Appreciate your answer and reply, will try your solution. Pardon me to ask one more question, ignore if you feel it silly,.. so if I add in the above docker file, when I run every time will it install over and over ?  If yes, how can we avoid that ?

Comment: There are 2 methods I think: 1) If you add the install in Dockerfile, and upgrade your image, here yours is `image 'abcdtest'`, then the build of docker image is outside of jenkins. You did it in advance, so when jenkins run, it won't install the package again and again, you already have a pre-ok environment there. 2) If you add the install in jenkins `stage->step->script->sh`, then you may also ok, but the install will happen every time you kick off this jenkins project.

Comment: I have updated my docker file and committed the changes, still it is giving the same error. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: Where you store `image 'abcdtest'`? When you said `commit` what does it mean?

Comment: docker file creation is a separate repo in our project, that is tied up to jenkins seprately. So now I have run that in jenkins to create a new update image file as you suggested.

Comment: Now that error disappeared and started running the pipeline

Comment: Could you please help me with this issue if you have spare time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67896803/jenkins-is-not-getting-the-url-value-passed-it-says-null