# Jenkins is not getting the url value passed, it says null

Tags: jenkins, cypress

While running my tests in jenkins pipeline, it says you have passed the `cy.request()` url as `null`. I have mentioned all of the env variables in jenkins. Could someone please advise what is the problem here ?

Error:
`CypressError:` cy.request()`requires a`url`. You did not provide a` url`.`

my `.env` file:

```
CYPRESS_TEST_USERNAME=Test1
CYPRESS_TEST_PASSWORD=BooksTest1234
CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://my-test-url.com/books/
CYPRESS_API_URL=https://my-test-url.com/api/v1.0/books/
```

my jenkins file

```
def channel = '#jenkins-cypress'
def ARTEFACT_DIR=""
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Clone books-suite') {
        steps {
            dir('books-co') {
                script {
                    checkout([
                        $class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [
                            [name: "origin/develop"]
                        ],
                        extensions: [
                            [$class: 'CleanCheckout'],
                            [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: '**'],
                            [$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 1, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: true, timeout: 10]
                        ],
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[
                            credentialsId: 'fsdf68fs61-esdfsdf56546-92ea-7345bcfsfsdfb3d391',
                            url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket_url_location'
                        ]],
                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                        submoduleCfg: []
                    ])
                    ARTEFACT_DIR="${env.WORKSPACE}/artefacts/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run cypress') {
        steps {
            script {
                mattermostSend color: 'good', channel: channel, message: "**STARTING** - Cypress starts (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}>)"
                sh "mkdir -p \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}/videos\""
                sh "mkdir -p \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}/screenshots\""
                def baseUrlConfig="-e CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://my-test-url.com/books/"
                def screenshotsFolderConfig="screenshotsFolder=/artefacts/screenshots"
                def videosFolderConfig="videosFolder=/artefacts/videos"
                def config = "--config ${screenshotsFolderConfig},${videosFolderConfig}"
                def cypressArgs = "run --headless --browser chrome ${config} --project /books-suite"
                sh """
                docker run ${baseUrlConfig} \
                  -v \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}:/artefacts\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_OUTPUT_FILE=\"/artefacts/report.html\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_TEST_USERNAME=\"Test1\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_TEST_PASSWORD=\"BooksTest1234\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_BASE_URL=\"https://my-test-url.com/books/\" \
                  -e CYPRESS_API_URL=\"https://my-test-url.com/api/v1.0/books/\" \
                  
                  cypress:latest \
                    /node_modules/.bin/cypress ${cypressArgs}
                """
                mattermostSend color: 'good', channel: channel, message: "**SUCCESSED** - Cypress CI passed successfully (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}>)"
            }
        }
    }
  }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                USER_ID = get_uid()
                GROUP_ID = get_gid()
                sh """
                    docker run --user ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} \
                      -v \"${ARTEFACT_DIR}:/artefacts\" \
                      -v \"${env.WORKSPACE}/books-co:/books\" \
                      -e JSON_DIR=\"/books/tests/cypress/cucumber-json\" \
                      -e OUTPUT_FILE=\"/artefacts/report.html\" \
                      cypress-books-report:latest
                """
            }
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: "artefacts/${BUILD_NUMBER}/**/*", fingerprint: true

            emailext attachmentsPattern: "artefacts/${BUILD_NUMBER}/**/*",
                body: '${FILE, path="' + "artefacts/${BUILD_NUMBER}/report.html" + '"}',
                mimeType: 'text/html',
                to: 'first.lastman@books.com',
                subject: "Cypress Jenkins Build ${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME}"

            sh "rm -Rf artefacts/${BUILD_NUMBER}"

            mattermostSend color: 'good', channel: channel, message: "**SUCCESSED** - Cypress CI report generated (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}>)"
        }
        failure {
            mattermostSend color: 'danger', channel: channel, message: "**FAILED** - cypress CI failed (<${env.BUILD_URL}|build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}> - <${env.BUILD_URL}console|click here to see the console output>)"
        }
    }
}

def get_uid() {
    node('master') {
        return sh(script: "id -u ${USER}", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
}

def get_gid() {
    node('master') {
        return sh(script: "id -g ${USER}", returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
}
```

plugins/index.js :

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber()),
        on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
            console.log("Print browser name: "+browser.name);

            if (browser.name === 'chrome' || browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
                launchOptions.args.push('--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies') // bypass 401 unauthorised access on chromium-based browsers
                return launchOptions
            }

            if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
                // launch chrome using incognito
                launchOptions.args.push(' --incognito')
                return launchOptions
            }

            if (browser.name === 'chrome' && browser.isHeadless) {
                launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
                return launchOptions
            }
        });

    config = dotenvPlugin(config)                                                                           
    return config

};
```

commands.js file

```
Cypress.Commands.add("loginReq", () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: Cypress.env('BASE_URL'), // baseUrl is prepended to url
    form: true, 
    body: {
      loginUsername: Cypress.env('TEST_USERNAME'),
      loginPassword: Cypress.env('TEST_PASSWORD')
    }
  }).then((response)=>{
    console.log("login success: "+response);
  })
});
```

Comment: it should `url: Cypress.env('CYPRESS_BASE_URL'), // baseUrl is prepended to url`  ? Right ?

Comment: In cypress somewhere it is mentioned that if we have a` .env` variable like this  `CYPRESS_BASE_URL`  we can give `url: Cypress.env('BASE_URL')` inside the test and it will take the value for that.

Comment: I was following as per their documentation. As you suggested in order to run in jenkins should we give the full value ?

Answer (score 1):

When you set `CYPRESS_BASE_URL`, Cypress config will look like:

```json
{
    "baseUrl": "your set base url",
    "env": {

    }
}
```

You can have a look when you run `cypress open` and then go to Settings in the opened test runner.

The problem is that `Cypress.env()` reads variables from `env` object, where your base url is *not* set because `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` sets `baseUrl` property, not `env.baseUrl` property.

If you want to set `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` and access it from your tests, then you have to invoke it with `Cypress.config().baseUrl`.

However, you don't really need to call (not in your example) `Cypress.config().baseUrl` because Cypress does that automatically for you, so:

```js
cy
  .visit('/');
```

really means that Cypress prepends the base url for you. The same goes for `cy.request()`, so in your example, you can delete it from there.

Comment: In the cy.request url, if we mention `url: Cypress.config().baseUrl ` will it work ? Why the following doesn't work ``url: Cypress.env('BASE_URL')``` any idea ? It is running smoothly in my local computer...but not on Jenkins.

Comment: I have tried two things here running in local. 
1) .env has following baseUrl set `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` and my cypress.json doesn't have base url and I also have set url in my ``cy.reques( {  
   url: Cypress.config().baseUrl
})`` now it  is getting value from .env file.
2) Remove the baseUrl  `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` from the .env file and provide baseUrl in cypress.json file and I also have set url in my ``cy.reques( {  
   url: Cypress.config().baseUrl
})`` now it  is getting value from cypress.json file.

Comment: So in jenkins why if we gave in ``cy.request ( {  url: Cypress.env('BASE_URL')`...)`` will that not work ?

Comment: @soccerway: I actually explained that in my answer. `Cypress.env('BASE_URL')` looks for the variable in `env` object inside your Cypress.json. But `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` sets `baseUrl` property, not `env.baseUrl` property.

Comment: Thank you, will the jenkins be able to read other .env values ?